# mysql database allow external access from specific ip only ubuntu 16

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I would like to allow one of my mysql database access from an external, however I would like to restrict it to be access from 1 ip only. Is there any way to do so:

1. only apply the setting to 1 database
2. only allow access to that database from a specific ip

My server is ubuntu 16.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MySQL user can be created for a [specific origin address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html):

```
CREATE USER bob@'202.1.1.3' IDENTIFIED BY 'very very secure password';
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO bob@'202.1.1.3'
```

Provided no other GRANTS are given to `db`, then the `bob` user from '202.1.1.2' is the only allowed user.

Its generally more secure to give a ssh tunnel access, or access on a non-standard port however. Publicly accessible database servers will have their authentication brute forced.

Comment: Thank you! I am kind of new to this, any reference for setting a ssh tunnel access, or access on a non-standard port?

Comment: The other database on the server, how are they accessed? Do they need remote access? For the asked about database access, Is this a person or a script accessing the database remotely?

Comment: Just want to run some sql to the remote mysql database and the sql script is run by php.

Comment: A 32k-42k port number. Set the `port=` in a configuration file in `/etc/mysql/... my.cnf` see what files are there, on may have it already. Being a script get a large random password (< 40 characters there is a silent limit somewhere in some cases).